# Is there any way to export a function signature in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I would like to export a function coming from another module in an interface or a namespace, but could not find any appropriate syntax. What would be the syntax to do so ?

```
import {myFunction} from './a'

export interface MyInterface
{
    MyFunction=typeof myFunction;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, it was as simple as that:

```
import {myFunction} from './a'

export interface MyInterface
{
    MyFunction:typeof myFunction;
}
```